# How to load data from multiple subfolders in datalake to a dataframe in azure databricks

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have few of the csv file which is present in multiple subfolders in azure datalake. I want to take all the data present in those files and load them to a dataframe in azure databricks. The structure of the folder and subfolder in databricks is given below

```
Folder name -> YearName2019 -> Month1 ->filename
                            -> Month2 ->filename
                             .
                            ->Month12 ->filename


           -> YearName2020  ->Month1  ->filename
                            .
                            .
                            ->Month12 ->filename
```

I am trying to read the data from all the subfolders using the following code but it's not Working

```
df=spark.read.load('/FolderName/*' ,format='csv' ,sep=',' ,header='True' ,inferSchema=True)
```

Comment: Spark will load the subfolders for you, so just `spark.read.csv('/path/to/Folder name')`

Comment: @Pltc gave you the answer already, but if you have issues about reading multiple files in different paths, let us know.

Comment: When I am just providing folder name and setting InferSchema to True then it's returning error that 'unable to infer schema for CSV and it must be provided manually' and on providing the schema manually, It running fine but the dataframe is not returning any data